# Why wget records the contents from a live stream on local server but doesn't work on remote server?

Tags: php, bash, wget, remote-server, live-streaming

I am trying to record a live stream by using following code.

```
system("wget -O $root/record_1.mp3 -c http://192.99.8.170:8098/stream/1;",$output);
var_dump($output);
```

It doesn't fetch anything into `record_1.mp3` file but only generates the file when I try it on the server whereas If I try the same code on my local server then it starts recording the live stream into the `record_1.mp3` file. Its been hours that I'm stuck into it but I'm unable to figure out what is going on?

**NOTE:** On the remote server If I try something like

```
$val = system("wget -O $root/record_1.html -c https://www.google.com/doodle4google/history.html",$output);
```

Then it successfully executes the code, creates the html file and puts contents into it.

Can you please tell me whats going wrong?
Thanks!

Comment: Then it successfully executes the code, creates the html file and puts contents into it.? so what's the problem then?

Comment: But doesn't work if I try recording from a live stream.

Comment: There's not enough information to help you.  What's the STDERR output from wget?  What's the HTTP response code?  Run the command outside of PHP and see what happens.  You're probably being blocked by the remote server.